# Click event using Class in Angular Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using Highchrt and i want click on lengend on load.

I am using angular ionic so how can i click `.highcharts-legend-item` class in  `ngOnInit() {}` function.

I want click tthis class on page is load with angular ionic.

In javascript `$(.highcharts-legend-item).click();` but i dont knw in anular ionic.

[image: The edit]

Answer (score 2):

If you're using  Ionic, you're still in a browser, so you can use the standard html-js API.

### Pure JavaScript Approach

`document.querySelector('.highcharts-legend-item').click()`

### Angular Approach

Use [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) and click the element programmatically

ts:

```js
 constructor(private elem: ElementRef){}

 ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector('.highcharts-legend-item').click();
 }
```

Comment: Viewchild is not a solution for this scenario. highcharts-legend-item is not created by user. It is part of highcharts graph library @Marcell Kiss

Comment: im using class  not id `.highcharts-legend-item'` is a class. default from highchart i  cannt edit this so.

Comment: I see, I corrected my answer according to your feedback. You can still use ElementRef if you wanna go the Angular way